# ElementType in template constraints

Tags: templates, d

How [std.range.ElementType](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#ElementType) should be used in template constraints?

I assumed this way, but I was wrong

```
import std.range;
auto f(T)(T x)
    if (ElementType!(T) is uint) // adding this line causes lot of error messages 
                                // first of which is:  found ')' when expecting '.' following uint
{
    return x;
}
f(map!"a"([1,2,3,4]));
```

Comment: It only happens in CTFE I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **is** expression is not the same as the *is* operator. Documentation on the is expression is here: http://dlang.org/expression.html#IsExpression. The *is* operator does a bitwise comparison of values whereas the **is** expression compares types (and does crazy pattern matching). Your constraint should be written like this:

```
auto f(T)(T x)
     if (is(ElementType!(T) == uint))
```

Or, if you want to match anything implicitly convertible to a uint as well:

```
auto f(T)(T x)
     if (is(ElementType!(T) : uint))
```

Further, I've fixed your invocations of ElementType, adding the "!" where appropriate; ElementType is a template, not a function.